# How can I separate the firebase credentials from the production build that I get in Angular 2+?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularbuild

I need to build the same code and connect to different it to different firebase backends, I have to build it each time by changing the firebase credentials in the source files.

Is there a easy to achieve this ?

Comment: Use environment variables. A .env file in development and real environment variables in production

Comment: See the answer of the marked duplicate. I believe this is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: No it is something different, although I found my answer [here](https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-use-environment-variables-to-configure-your-angular-application-without-a-rebuild/)    @Igor